# Problems while trying to compress into a single page the following CV template?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column, multicolumn

I am using [this](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) cv template which looks like this:

[image]

How can I compress all the CV into a two columns format, in order to have all the sections in one page?, I tried to:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% Awesome CV LaTeX Template
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV
%
% Author:
% Claud D. Park <posquit0.bj@gmail.com>
% http://www.posquit0.com
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Configuration
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Themes: Awesome-CV
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

%%% Override a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
\fontdir[fonts/]

%%% Configure a directory location for sections
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}

%%% Override color
% Awesome Colors: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange
%                 awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
%% Color for highlight
% Define your custom color if you don't like awesome colors
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8}
%% Colors for text
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

%%% Override a separator for social informations in header(default: ' | ')
%\headersocialsep[\quad\textbar\quad]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     3rd party packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Needed to divide into several files
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{multicol}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Claud D.}{Park}
\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 22738, Rep. of KOREA}
\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843} 
%%% Social
\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}
%%% Optionals
\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert}
\quote{``Make the change that you want to see in the world."}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {Claud D. Park~~~·~~~Résumé}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader
\begin{multicols}[2]
%%% Import contents
\import{\sectiondir}{education.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{experience.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{extracurricular.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{honors.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{presentation.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{writing.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{committees.tex}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

However, I got this output:

[image]

Alternatively, I tried with `\begin{multicols*}` however, its not working. Any idea of how to make that the text dont overflow the next column section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{multicol}


\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\columnwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\columnwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}

\renewenvironment{cvhonors}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.5cm} L{\columnwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering}
    {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)}
    {Pohang, S.Korea}
    {Mar. 2010 - Aug. 2017}
    {
      \begin{cvitems}
        \item {Got a Chun Shin-Il Scholarship which is given to promising students in CSE Dept.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}

\cvsection{Honors \& Awards}

\cvsubsection{International}
\begin{cvhonors}
  \cvhonor
    {Finalist}
    {DEFCON 25th CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
    {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
    {2017}
  \cvhonor
    {Finalist}
    {DEFCON 22nd CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
    {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
    {2014}
\end{cvhonors}


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The overflowing text in the image you have shown is caused by the way, commands like `\cventry` are defined in `awesome-cv.cls`. If you compare the original definition with the redefinition in the above MWE, you can see that the only difference is that the original uses `\textwidth` while the redefinition uses `\columnwidth` instead.

Please also note that it is `\begin{multicols}{2}` instead of `\begin{multicols}[2]` as in your example.

Lastly, please note, that the above MWE should give you an idea on how to modify the code. I have not been able to extensively test it for all the entries you have shown in your example.